# Priting from a web page

Tags: 20.04

I have a new G3200 Canon that will print from LibreOffice Writer but will not print from a web page. I use Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: If using snap version of browser, probably why.  Snaps have less permissions than regular deb versions to do things like reading other drives or printing.

Comment: According to Firefox I have version 86.0.1 - no mention of snaps anywhere

Comment: Software store should show which version of Firefox you have snap or deb.  If store has a permissions button beside the remove button, then it is a snap.  Your problem is  common with snap programs.  Either adjust permissions, or install deb version.